# How can I get a Logic App to run more often than once per second?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

For the logic app workflow I am working on, I need the logic app to run more regularly than once per second which seems to be the minimum length of time with a recurrence trigger.

Does anyone have any bright ideas how to do this please as ideally I need it to run 5 or more times a second, thank you.

Comment: Can I ask what that will do?  What's your use case?  There might be a better way.  Also, depending on how long it will take to run, it's unlikely to finish before the next run starts and if you think about it, exponentially, that will result in A LOT of running jobs.  It will end up failing due to execution exhaustion.  It won't just keep spawning.

Comment: Thanks @Skin. 

The use case is to take a dataset, currently in Azure SQL, prepare it in the required format and call a REST API on Oracle Fusion Financials with the data one row at a time.

All the time new data to be processed may be appearing in the same dataset in Azure SQL via another process.

Do you think it would make sense to use a different approach here? Maybe have a trigger for when a new line of data arrives in the SQL table and call the API? Open to suggestions thank you.

Comment: Hmmmmm, first question is, **do you need it that frequently or could you bundle the calls to Oracle every minute or so?**  Can the application sitting over the top of the SQL DB do the work for you and maybe route the messages to another location?  Basic thoughts are to decouple the inserts to SQL with the calls to Oracle.  That may introduce other challenges though.